# Installing bower and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I'm trying to set up Bower within a Rails 4 application, specifically I am trying to install the **voice-elements** web component: http://zenorocha.github.io/voice-elements/

I've considered using bower-rails but would prefer to keep it as vanilla as possible, but I am a bit lost. So far I have followed these steps:

Created **.bowerrc** in rails root

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

Add to **application.rb**

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

From rails root

```
bower init
```

From vendor/assets

```
bower install --save voice-elements
```

[image: vendor tree]

Example code in a rails **show** view

```
<voice-player id="mi-elemento" accent="es-ES" text="Me gusta la gasolina"></voice-player>
<script>
var form = document.querySelector('#mi-form'),
    element = document.querySelector('#mi-elemento');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    element.speak();
});
</script>
```

**I am not sure where to go from here. How can I tell Rails how to use the voice-elements library in vendor/assets?**

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative: would you consider using `rails-assets.org`? No need to install bower, and you can just install bower packages as regular gems.

In your case you would add the following line at the top of your `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
```

and then add a line for your package, gems are calles `rails-assets-<package-name>`, so in your case that would be

```
gem 'rails-assets-voice-elements'
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try this approach, and failed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340063/infinite-loop-when-installing-voice-elements-via-rails-assets-org  I also logged a ticket with rails-assets but it won't be fixed: https://github.com/rails-assets/rails-assets/issues/171

Comment: This method has never worked for me, always get an infinite loop error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229385/rails-gemfile-infinite-loop-when-using-rails-assets-for-npm-components

Answer (score 2):

There is quite nice `gem` you can use to integrate `Bower` with `Rails`: [`bower-rails`](https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails/). Try this way.

Comment: Hi how would I install the voice-elements package using this method?

Comment: As the documentation says:
Run the initializer to generate a sample Bowerfile inside the Rails root and a `config/initializers/bower_rails.rb` config file: `rails g bower_rails:initialize` and then add `voice-elements` as an asset.

Comment: could you outline the steps on how to correctly add voice-elements using bower-rails?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the "usage" instructions for voice-element? It looks like you need to include some bower-created javascript (you should be able to require that in `application.js`), then add some `<link>` tags to your layout pointing to two HTML files.

Try adding this to `application.js`:

```
//= require platform/platform
```

Then add these lines to the `<head>` section in your layout:

```
<link rel="import" href="<%= asset_path 'voice-elements/dist/voice-player.html' %>">
<link rel="import" href="<%= asset_path 'voice-elements/dist/voice-recognition.html' %>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have installed the voice-element code.. the problem I am having is making it accessible to Rails.

Comment: It's a client-side library, so I don't think you need to make it available to Rails per se. You just need it somewhere the client can get at it. It looks like you've added it to the asset path, so you just need to reference it now (just like any other asset).

Comment: This is my question ... not sure how to do this part. There seem to be multiple components and I am not sure which directory to add to the asset pipeline. See the screenshot.

Comment: I added a couple steps to the answer that you can try. If that doesn't work, you should probably just install bower-rails :).

Comment: Thanks James, I tried the steps above. The require failed for some reason, despite the path added to application.rb as detailed in my original question. Happy to consider a bower-rails solution - how would I install the specific package this way?